# Jest unit coverage for $.ajax

Tags: jquery, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I want to test `$.ajax` method in my react method using jest and enzyme for unit coverage.

```
$.ajax({
      url: `url`,
      type: "GET"
    }).done(data => {
        //dosomething
      }).fail(err => {
       //do something else
      });
```

How can I mock `$.ajax` to get test covered for success and error part?

Comment: Don't test external 3rd party code. Are you really trying to test that in either case *your callback code* (i.e. the do something, or do something else) correctly executes?

Comment: Yeah. I want to test the callback execution

Comment: I would say at this point it would be better to your callbacks in isolation and not muck with mocking your jquery. You really want to test that upon receiving `data` or `err` that your callbacks then function correctly. How they got `data` or `err` is really irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

Mock `$.ajax` using a jest mock function.

```
$.ajax = jest.fn().mockImplementation(options => {
  let instance = {
    done: fn => {
      if (options.success) fn("test passed");
      return instance;
    },
    fail: fn => {
      if (!options.success) fn("test failed");
      return instance;
    }
  };
  return instance;
});
```

[image: Edit flamboyant-cookies-ecd56]

**Note:** I recommend testing your callback functions separately from mocking 3rd party modules/functions.

Answer (score 1):

The following code works for mocking ajax response(done and fail case)-jest testcases @abbas ali :P

```
let  response={"rows":[{"dlvDate":"03/13/2020","sts":"SC","}],"errorMessage":null,"count":null,"data":null,"result":true};

let ajax_response_sucess=(response)=> {
  var deferred = $.Deferred().resolve(response);
  return deferred.promise();
}

let ajax_response_fail=(response)=> {
  var deferred = $.Deferred().reject(response);
  return deferred.promise();
}

  it("test for callModalService function", () => {
$.ajax=jest.fn=()=>{return ajax_response_sucess(response)}; 
wrapper.instance().callModalService()//call the function,which makes Api call

$.ajax=()=>{return ajax_response_fail(response)}; 
//call the function which makes Api call
 wrapper.instance().callModalService()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on the actual implementation, but in case you've got `$` defined globally e.g. login it from external file you can mock it in your test like this:

```
const mockAjax = {
  done: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
  fail: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
};

global.$ = {
  ajax: jest.fn(() => mockAjax)
};

// and then require your implementation
require('./path/to/ajax/call.js');


// and then you can use jest's .mock property
// https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions#mock-property
// to get your callback
const [ firstCall ] = mockAjax.done.calls;
const [ yourCallback ] = firstCall;

// and call it with mockData
yourCallback(mockData);
```

[working example](https://repl.it/repls/JauntySafeEditors)